# Printing astericks triangle using recursion

Tags: java

I am trying to print a triangle composed of asterisks using two methods, one to print it upwards, and one downwards. Printing it up is easy and I use the code

```
public static String printTriangleUp(int n)
{
    if( n <= 0 ) return "";

    String p = printTriangleUp(n - 1);
    p = p + "*";
    System.out.println(p);

    return p;
 }
```

And get the output looking like

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

However I can't find a way to make it look like

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to declare a String before you call the method so you can rely completely on the stack to increment and push the string up and pop the values off in the right order.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String p = "";
    printTriangleDown(5, p);
}   

public static String printTriangleDown(int n, String p){
if( n <= 0 ) return "";

p = p + "*";
printTriangleDown(n-1, p);
System.out.println(p);

return p;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The logic for your function should be:

> printTriangleUp(n) prints a triangle, with rows of stars in lengths n down to 1

So your recursive call, `printTriangleUp(n-1)`, would:

> print a triangle, with rows of stars in lengths n-1 down to 1

Which means the missing piece would be the top row of n stars, which would need to be done before the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

imho your original code is strange, that the method is on the same time printing something, and returning a string.

Your two problem will be easy if you make the function clear (all psuedo code of course):

```
printTriangleUp(i)
  if i == 0 :
    do nothing
  else :
    printTriangUp(i-1)
    print i stars
```

Similarly, for a downward triangle:

```
printTriangleDown(i)
  if i == 0 :
    do nothing
  else :
    print i stars
    printTriangDown(i-1)
```